# Opencart редактирования кода страниц

Tags: php, css, opencart, tpl

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь редактировать .tpl шаблоны и css файлы, все сохраняю перезаливаю на сервер, чищу куки. Страницы не обновляются, притом что сами шаблоны меняются (!). То есть где-то хранятся какие-то непонятные копии этих страниц. Вот как извиняюсь можно такую ерунду было написать?
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Файлы, которые вы пытаетесь менять, переписаны ocMod'ом по причине использования вами расширений, которые затрагивают данные файлы, и скопированы с изменениями в system/storage/modification с повторением структуры каталогов сайта. Обновить изменения в этом случае можете двумя дорогами - удалив всё нафиг из папки modification и обновив кеш через админку `Дополнения(Extensions)-Менеджер дополнений(Modifications)` Там в правом верхнем углу группа кнопок. Голубая сбрасывает системные кеши.